# OpenGl rotations and object movement

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to create a very basic planet movement (sun, earth moon represented as cubes).

As for now i managed to move one cube around another, but I have the following question... What will be the best way to move another cube (ex. the moon) around an already moving one?

I put them in motion using simple operations ex. for movement on x axis:

`d * Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 180.0)`

Where d is the distance from center or projection (dont know if i used this term right).
I thought about putting the "satellite" by calulating the distance of the already rotating cube and adding some parameter, but don't know how to make that planet like a "reference" for center of rotation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this by creating a composition of transformations. Say you want to orbit a planet around a central star. First the planet is moved into orbit, a translation, in say the x direction:

```
orbit_distance = translation_orbit · planet_center
```

followed by a rotation around the center.

```
orbit_position = rotation_orbit · orbit_distance
```

Or, you can write this in one line

```
orbit_position = rotation_orbit · translation_orbit · planet_center
```

It is important, that the order of operations matter, rotating first and then translating is not the same as first translating and then rotating. Or, in mathematical terms, geometrical transformations are not commutative.

In a 3 dimensional space all linear transformations can be described by linear equations in a 4 dimensional homogenous set of coordinates. I.e. you can use 4×4 matrices to express all kinds of linear geometrical transformations.

A rotatng moon orbiting a planet orbiting a sun:

```
R_orbit_planet · T_orbit_planet · R_orbit_moon · T_orbit_moon · R_rotation_moon
```

Comment: Thank You for explanation :)  so I should use the same matrices that i have used for moving the planet on orbit and multiply them with matrices responsible for moon movement?

Comment: @mjanisz1: If you want to save some computations (you want to), then yes.

Comment: And another question... In the assignment I have "Each of them rotates around its own axis. (you can define this axis in any way you think is appropriate)".    Do those matrix transformations define the axis of each body?

Comment: @mjanisz1: Sort of. Think about each of the matrices as defining a new local coordinate system, where the first 3 columns dafine the base vectors and the 4th the offset relative to the coordinate system it is "embedded" in. Embedding goes from left to right.